# Greatest N per Group in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, execution-plan, greatest-n-per-group

I want to find classical **Greatest N per Group**. I have two methods to solve this problem

1. `Dense_rank Over()` method
2. `Min Over()` method

Both work flawlessly. Now I want to find which one is better and why.

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #test
    (
        id    INT,
        NAME  VARCHAR(50),
        dates DATETIME
    );

WITH cte
    AS (SELECT TOP (100000) n = ( (Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.number) - 1) / 3) + 1
        FROM   [master]..spt_values a
            CROSS JOIN [master]..spt_values b)
INSERT INTO #test
SELECT n,
        Getdate() + n
FROM   cte ;
```

**Dense_rank Over() Method:**

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Dense_rank() OVER (partition BY NAME ORDER BY dates) AS rn,*
         FROM   #test)
SELECT id,
       NAME,
       dates
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

**Min Over() Method:**

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Min(dates) OVER (partition BY NAME) AS max_date,*
         FROM   #test)
SELECT id,
       NAME,
       dates
FROM   cte
WHERE  max_date = dates ;
```

To compare the performance I checked on execution plan which said both query cost is 50%. But `Max Over` method execution plan looks little complex. So any guidance here will be helpful. I don't have very good understanding in execution plans.

**Execution Plan:**(6 rows)

[image]

**Execution plan:**(100000 rows)

For `100000` rows the execution plan says

```
Dense_rank Over() Query cost : 46% 
Min Over() Query cost        : 54%
```

[image]

Comment: You should make a more realistic test, e.g. do you really not plan on having any indexes on your production tables, never mind an index that might help support this query?

Comment: Not to mention that the percents in the plans may not accurately represent the differences in performance. You should time your queries and compare the actual execution times.